# Android Photos and Gallery app do not respect EXIF date (except Android 10)

Tags: android, gallery, photo, exif

I have an app that downloads an image file as a byte array, stores it as a temporary file and then has it displayed using an ACTION_VIEW intent. This results in the photo being opened in the Photos or Gallery app.

This all works fine, except the date that is shown in those apps is the current date. This makes sense of course, but I'd like it to show the actual date of when the photo was taken.

So preferably I'd just like the new file to have a different creation date. However this seems not to be possible (correct me if I'm wrong).

Alternatively I can add the date to the EXIF data instead. I tried this and it does seem to work, but only in my Android 10 emulator. On an Android 11 emulator and my Android 11 and 9 device it does not work and it still shows the current date. I also added EXIF data to mirror the image. The image appears mirrored everywhere. So my conclusion is that the EXIF data *is* read and processed.

I added both TAG_DATETIME, TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED and TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL.

On the left it shows the current date on Android 11 and on the right Android 10 that shows the 2017 date that I want. The trees are mirrored upside down on both sides:

[image]

What would be the most effective way to download a photo from an API and have it correctly shown its date in a photos/gallery app? Is it somehow possible to keep the original file's creation date?

Comment: You could indirectly set file times: create a ZIP file where you manipulate that file's time attribute(s), then unpack it ([original idea](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/general-computing/changing-files-metadata-in-android/)).

Comment: Yes maybe I can have the server create a ZIP file containing the image file with the right date and have that extracted on the device keeping the original creation date. Thanks for the idea!